# How to run jenkins behing NGINX?

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins to be accessed only behind NGINX.

Currently Jenkins works on port 8080 which is exposed to run without SSL.

I have tried the following configuration:

```
        location /jenkins/ {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
```

If I try to access my url/jenkins it returns a *404* while trying to direct to jenkins login page.
The *404* is being returned by the nextJs app working on  **/**  location of the NGINX server.

Both Nginx and Jenkins are running in Docker containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to configure Jenkins with a context path. You can do this by passing a launch parameter `--prefix=/jenkins`. Then your NginX rule should work.

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

If you still get any invalid redirects Try adding a [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) to your Nginx configurations. Which will rewrite all redirect URLs with the correct context.